# I like a/the new film which is called ... (which article can be used here?)

Tags: articles

I'm confused which article can be used here - "a" or "the"?

> **I like a new film** which is called “...”.
>
> **I like the new film** which is called “...”.

When we speak about a thing first time we use "a". But here I speak about a certain new film, so could you explain please which article must be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would more often say, **I like that new film "..."** or **There's a new film I like called "..."**. In the UK "I like a ..." is often used in, for example, "I like a ripe fig" to mean "I like ripe figs." So "I like a new film" is a misleading opening.

**I like the new film called "..."** is better, but we would generally say, **I like *that* new film [called] "..."**, or simply **I like that new film "..."**, which allow the listener to say s/he's heard of it or seen it.

If we're fairly sure the listener *won't* have heard of it we say, **There's a new film I like called "..."**.